# Shiny/R: Outputs not displaying

Tags: r, shiny

so I'm trying to make a tax calculation app. In the sidebar I'm using tabsetPanel to display two panels with different inputs relating to the individual and then tax rates.

The mainPanel will also be using tabsetPanel where I plan to plot graphs etc. I have an update button that doesn't seem to be working.

```
ui.R
```

Looks like this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("flatTax"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  h1("Flat Tax Calculator"),
  helpText("Input your information below and see how a flat tax could
affect your tax bill."),

  #Individual Specific Variables
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("You",
    numericInput(inputId = "incomeNum",
                label = "Your annual income:",
                value = 0
    ),

    textInput(inputId = "testText",
              label = "Test Input"
              ),
    ),

    tabPanel("Tax Settings", 
    sliderInput(inputId = "basicIncome", 
                label = "Choose a monthly basic income", 
                value = 600, min = 0, max = 1200, step = 50
    ),

    sliderInput(inputId = "taxFree", 
                label = "Choose a tax free allowance", 
                value = 10000, min = 0, max = 20000, step = 250
    ),

    sliderInput(inputId = "flatIncomeTax", 
                label = "Choose a flat tax rate", 
                value = 50, min = 0, max = 100, step = 1
    ),

    sliderInput(inputId = "flatPropertyTax", 
                label = "Choose a land value tax rate", 
                value = 1, min = 0, max = 100, step = 1
  )),

  # Action Button
  actionButton(inputId = "updateButton", 
               label = "Update"),
  plotOutput("text")
)
),


mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Summary",
      h3("Test Output", textOutput("test"),
      h3("Your new income tax bill is:", textOutput("incomeFT")),
      h3("Your new property tax bill is:", textOutput("propertyFT")),
      textOutput("annualBasicIncome")
        )
        ),
    tabPanel("Graphs",
          h3("Placeholder"),
          h3("Holding the place"),
          h3("Plaice holster")   
        )
      )
)
)
))


server.R
```

Looks like this:

```
shinyServer(
function(input, output) {


#action button stuff
incomeFT <- eventReactive(input$updateButton, {
  ((input$incomeNum-input$taxFree)/100*input$flatIncomeTax)
})

output$incomeFT <- renderPrint({
  incomeFT()
})

propertyFT <- eventReactive(input$updateButton, {
  input$propertyNum/100*input$flatPropertyTax
})

output$propertyFT <- renderPrint({
  propertyFT()
})    

annualBasicIncome <- eventReactive(input$updateButton, {
  switch(as.numeric(input$relStat),
         return((input$basicIncome*12)+((input$basicIncome*12)*input$childNum)),
         return((2*(input$basicIncome*12))+((input$basicIncome*12)*input$childNum))
  )
  })

output$annualBasicIncome <- renderPrint({
  annualBasicIncome()
})

test <- eventReactive(input$updateButton, {
  input$testText
})

output$test <- renderText({
  test()
})
})
```

Without reactivity it seems to work, but the button makes it less distracting to use. I've tried using verbatimTextOutput instead of textOutput but grey bars are sent across the main panel with not outputs in.

Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the `actionButton` does not work inside the `tabsetPanel`. If you put it outside it (and inside `sidebarPanel`) it will work. I suggest you try to use one `actionButton` for each `tabPanel`. I haven't try it, but I believe it should work. Please, if you try it, let me know the results.

Cheers.